# Application crash at building because of expo-av on mobile

Tags: react-native, expo

Hey i'm a dev web who got a new computer and i'm trying to reinstall all my mobile app. They are all working with my new android setup (I'm on windows) exept this one. And honestly i really don't know what is happening here because i found nothing about this error on the web so i'm asking for help here if you can resolve this with me. When i do a ./gradlew build this is the mistake who is showing up.

I don't think it's a setup problem but i'm not sure either because on my older computer the app was working..

This app use some expo stuff but it's not a proper expo app.

```
Task :expo-av:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Users\puaud\OneDrive\Bureau\BonnieAndCloud\Dev\Mobile\seducia-app\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVModule.java:127: error: incompatible types: org.unimodules.core.Promise cannot be converted to 
expo.modules.core.Promise
    Permissions.askForPermissionsWithPermissionsManager(mModuleRegistry.getModule(Permissions.class), promise, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
                                                                                                      ^
C:\Users\puaud\OneDrive\Bureau\BonnieAndCloud\Dev\Mobile\seducia-app\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVModule.java:132: error: incompatible types: org.unimodules.core.Promise cannot be converted to 
expo.modules.core.Promise
    Permissions.getPermissionsWithPermissionsManager(mModuleRegistry.getModule(Permissions.class), promise, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
                                                                                                   ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\puaud\OneDrive\Bureau\BonnieAndCloud\Dev\Mobile\seducia-app\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\player\PlayerData.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-av:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 32s
```

Appreciate all the help !